# ".sock" does not exist error; connect() error

Tags: nginx, django

I'm trying to set up my Mezzanine/Django project on a virtual Ubuntu 14.04 box on Linode, but get a "502 Bad Gateway error" when trying to navigate to my site in my browser.

I'm following the instructions here: https://linode.com/docs/web-servers/nginx/deploy-django-applications-using-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04.

I ran `git clone` in `/home/django/`, so everything's in a folder named `FOLDER`.

`/home/django/` has these directories: `Env/` and `FOLDER/`.

This should give some idea of what `FOLDER/` tree looks like:

```
FOLDER
- product_blog
-- product_blog
--- settings.py
--- wsgi.py
-- manage.py
```

In my `settings.py`, I have:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["PUBLIC IP OF MY LINODE UBUNTU INSTANCE HERE"]
```

`wsgi.py` has this:

```
"""
WSGI config for product_blog project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from mezzanine.utils.conf import real_project_name

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE",
                      "%s.settings" % real_project_name("product_blog"))

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

`/etc/uwsgi/sites/product_blog.ini` has this:

```
[uwsgi]
project = product_blog
base = /home/django

chdir = %(base)/%(project)
home = %(base)/Env/%(project)
module = %(project).wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 2

socket = %(base)/%(project)/%(project).sock
chmod-socket = 664
vacuum = true
```

`/etc/init/uwsgi.conf` has this:

```
description "uWSGI"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]
respawn

env UWSGI=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi
env LOGTO=/var/log/uwsgi.log

exec $UWSGI --master --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites --die-on-term --uid django --gid www-data --logto $LOGTO
```

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/product_blog` has this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/django/FOLDER;
    }

    location / {
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:/home/django/FOLDER/product_blog/product_blog.sock;
    }
}
```

When I go to the IP address for the Linode box, I see a 502 Bad Gateway error.

`/var/log/uwsgi.log` has this...

```
*** has_emperor mode detected (fd: 6) ***
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from product_blog.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.17 (64bit) on [Sun Apr 22 17:17:56 2018] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.4 on 22 April 2018 19:53:45
os: Linux-4.15.12-x86_64-linode105 #1 SMP Thu Mar 22 02:13:40 UTC 2018
nodename: ubuntu-linode
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /etc/uwsgi/sites
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
chdir() to /home/django/product_blog
chdir(): No such file or directory [core/uwsgi.c line 2629]
chdir(): No such file or directory [core/uwsgi.c line 1644]
Sun Apr 22 17:17:56 2018 - [emperor] curse the uwsgi instance product_blog.ini (pid: 4238)
Sun Apr 22 17:17:59 2018 - [emperor] removed uwsgi instance product_blog.ini
```

And `/var/log/nginx/error.log` has this (identifying info removed):

```
2018/04/22 17:18:14 [crit] 3953#0: *9 connect() to unix:/home/django/FOLDER/product_blog/product_blog.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 73.49.35.42, server: mydomain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/home/django/FOLDER/product_blog/product_blog.sock:", host: "ADDRESS TO LINODE BOX"
```

It seems that `product_blog.sock` is supposed to be somewhere in my directory, but it is not there. How do I fix the 502 error so that I can navigate my browser to the Linode box's address and see a working website?

Comment: Fix the socket path.

Comment: @MichaelHampton What must I change to do that? Where is the socket path?

Comment: It's in your ini file and in your nginx configuration.

Comment: @MichaelHampton What do I change the path to in each file?

Comment: It doesn't matter much. They just need to be the same!